# How to make ghostscript create PDF with initial view as "dual-spread first-on-right"?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I create PDF from few different PDFs using ghostscript from command line. All files I make have single page initial view.

[image: Current]

It is possible to force them to have initial view as dual page with first page on right side?

[image: what i need]

It look like I need something like `pdfmark`. There is something about initial view of PDF, but nothing about dual page view.

It is also called "even spreads" or "dual (even pages left)".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pdfmark operator to alter the DOCVIEW in the PDF file, and you can have that set the page mode.

However, as of the time of writing the page mode does not allow you to specify the layout you want. If you have a PDF file which opens like that, then you 'might' be able to copy the DOCVIEW parameters from it and use those in a pdfmark to create a new file.

Currently I don't know of any way for a PDF file to instruct Acrobat to open that way though.